# How to find the content root tag on a webpage

Tags: php, html, symfony, web-crawler

I need to find the main content of a webpage and extract it to save in the database.

The Evernote Webclipper and other plugins - I use them for Chrome -, to easy the reading of a webpage, are able to find the main content of a webpage and remove all other distractions, reformatting the text in a bigger font size and a more readable font family.

I'd like to build a similar feature as I need to save a particular page of a website, and save only its main content (the terms and service page and the privacy policies), removing sidebars, headers, and so on.

I'm going to build this thing in PHP, using the Symfony's Crawler Component, but I cannot figure out how can I evaluate each single tag to find the main content of the processing webpage.

Any ideas?

The one that comes to my mind is to count the number of `p` tags and compute their average lenght, so, the higher the number of `p` in a tag and the higher their average lenght can give me some sort of guidance...

Answer (score 0):

Search engine results drive content trends of websites. Search engines attempt to extract meaningful content to display relevant search results. As search engines evolve, web developers work to deliver content that ranks higher and higher. This has lead to a nice structure of data in quality sites.

Most tools that extract meaningful content analyze the markup semantically. Search terms of interest are [`semantic markup`](https://www.google.com/search?q=semantic+markup+-html5) and `rich snippets`.

Comment: Yes, I know this. But I cannot rely on these technologies as the content is very often not well formatted as they are simply no-one reads pages (terms of service and privacy policies). More, I don't think extensions like the Evernote webclipper or others reliy on the markup itself. I think they perform some kind of calculations, maybe counting the number of paragraphs, for example...